# Problems determining a file's mime type in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

When I try to determine a file's mime type with `getPageContext().getServletContext().getMimeType()`, it returns `undefined` if the extension is in uppercase (e.g., `image.JPG`). Has anyone run into this before? I know there is `FileGetMimeType`, but that gives me another set of issues within the codebase in which I'm working. I am running ColdFusion 10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be a regression in ColdFusion 10 (it works fine on CF9). I'd go through the motions of raising a bug, but Adobe will more than likely say one or more of:

1. it's that way on purpose;
2. it's outwith their control because it's Tomcat that deals with that sort of thing;
3. those methods are undocumented in CFML therefore unsupported (although they *are* documented in the [ServletContext spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getMimeType%28java.lang.String%29))

None are particularly satisfactory, but it's an easy out for Adobe.

TBH, I'd just lowercase the filename before passing it to the function. It's not like it needs to be the *actual* name of a real file.

Comment: I'm working on an Ubuntu system, so if the extension is lowercase CF will return a file not found type error.

Comment: I can run `getMimeType()` with any random file name I like. The file didn't seem to need to actually exist in the file system.

Comment: I did not know that getMimeType() only uses the extension to determine type. Seems like fileGetMimeType is a better choice, as it will look at the actual type, not just the extension.

Comment: You do know that as of Adobe CF 10 there is the fileGetMimeType function? You can find out about it here: https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/FileGetMimeType

Comment: You mean as per it being mentioned in both the original question, as well as the comment you're commenting on? ;-)