# ckfinder 2.4.2 issues with capitalization and thumbs

Tags: ckeditor, ckfinder, ckeditor4.x

If I upload an image with a suffix .JPG the thumbnail will not display in the browse images area. I can select it and place it just fine, but the thumbnail will not display. If I change the suffix to lowercase .jpg on the server, the thumbnail will display. Is this a bug or something that can be fixed in the config? Using the ColdFusion connectors.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug caused by misfortunate behaviour of ColdFusion described here: [Problems determining a file's mime type in ColdFusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21177749/problems-determining-a-files-mime-type-in-coldfusion). Download version 2.5.0.1 (released a minute ago ;)) and the thumbnails should be working.